# natural numbers, square roots, modell

Tags: logic

My task is to formulate the statement:

"There exists a third root, which is the product of two square roots" in the model $(\mathbb{N}, +,\cdot,=,<)$

Therefore I have to model this:

$\sqrt[3]a=\sqrt{b}\sqrt{c}$

just by using natural numbers.

Unfortunately I don't know how it is done.
How do I model a root just by using natural numbers? This seems a little bit odd to me.

I would be very thankful, if someone gives me a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to formulate, or do you have to prove the sentence you wrote is true in that structure?

Comment: I have to formulate the sentence in that structure.

Comment: $x$ is a square root iff there exists an $y$ such that $y=x\cdot x$ ...

Comment: Yes, I already thought so, to get rid of the roots. But how can I be sure, that i never get something irrational and never leave the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: It doesn't matter if you leave the natural numbers or not, you merely have to formulate the statement. If you need to leave the natural numbers, that would me the statement is false, but that is of no concern. Consider for instance $\exists x(x+ x = 1)$..

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is the third root of $d$ could be defined as $(a\cdot a)\cdot a=d$.
Hence $a$ is third root iff $\exists d\colon  (a\cdot a)\cdot a=d$. (Of course this is trivially fulfilled for all $a$)

Comment: Right. But how can I be sure, that I never get an a, which is not an element of $\mathbb{N}$. Or is this irrelevant?

Comment: You don't have to worry about $a$ not being a natural number since the domain is defined as $\mathbb{N}$.